# Dynamic fixed navbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navbar on the side of my page and I want it to change its position from `fixed` to `absolute` at a certain point. I am basically trying to get it to appear like its been stopped by my footer as the user scrolls past it.

I am currently using this code,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#myNavbar").css("top",Math.min( 562 , 1020 - $(this).scrollTop() ) );
});
```

This works great on one of the pages as the scroll top defined. Unfortunately I need to repeat this behavior on 12 pages all with varying heights.

How would I need to approach this, calculating percentages? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give more details about your example: what are 562 and 1020 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is get the `scrollTop()` position of the footer. From there, you compare the `scrollTop()` of the nav bar (+ nab bar `height()`) and as soon as the navs `scrollTop()` + `height()` > the footers `scrollTop()`, you change the class of the nav bar `addClass('not-sticky')`. Where `.not-sticky{position:absolute}`. Hope this helps